# Azure Functions Consumption Timeout Alert

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How do you create an alert for when an Azure Function on the Consumption plan has timed out after 10 minutes? There used to be a signal in Application Insights called "Failures" that indicated this but it looks like Microsoft removed it. My old signal was whenever the total count of Failures was > 0 it would send me an email, but I don't see anything comparable anymore.

Comment: You can use a timer trigger signal in azure function  to set a time out. If your query is not this one, please provide here the brief info

Comment: @RithwikBojja I'm using a queue trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open your application insights, click on Alerts and Click on Create alert.**
**There you can select Custom Log Search in condition as below:**

[image]

**Then you use the below query:**

```
requests  
| where duration > 1000
```

[image]

**Then you can create alert over there, This is one way of getting alerts using Time Duration.**

[image]